# Error on Exporting to MSFS

Tags: export, error

In the past I have exported many objects to Microsoft Flight Simulator (MSFS) and not had this problem - see attached screenshot.
Granted I am considered new to Blender but as I said I have not had this issue before.  I have not made any changes to Blender still using ver. 3.1.0 as it is said to work best with MSFS.
The glTF 2.0 is ver 1.8.19 and the Microsoft Flight Simulator glTF Extension is ver 1.3.0[image: Blender Export Error.png]

Comment: If 'MSFS' is an external addon, you'll have to ask the addon author. The LTS version of Blender 3.x is 3.3.6 so you could try installing that version to see if it helps. (Both versions can be installed and run at the same time.)

Comment: I just fixed my problem after doing extensive research on the internet.  By removing the addons folders as well as the models folder, then closing Blender, then adding back in those two folders, then opening Blender and installing the addons again.   Did an export and all went very well.  It seems there must have been some corrupt file or files.